# Changing LinkedHashMapValues

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, setvalue

Below is data from 2 linkedHashMaps:

```
valueMap:   { y=9.0, c=2.0, m=3.0, x=2.0}
formulaMap: { y=null, ==null, m=null, *=null, x=null, +=null, c=null, -=null, (=null, )=null, /=null}
```

What I want to do is input the the values from the first map into the corresponding positions in the second map. Both maps take **String,Double** as parameters.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entryNumber: valueMap.entrySet()){
   double doubleOfValueMap = entryNumber.getValue();
   for(String StringFromValueMap: strArray){
      for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entryFormula: formulaMap.entrySet()){          
         String StringFromFormulaMap = entryFormula.toString();
         if(StringFromFormulaMap.contains(StringFromValueMap)){
           entryFormula.setValue(doubleOfValueMap);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem with doing this is that it will set all of the values i.e. y,m,x,c to the value of the last double. Iterating through the values won't work either as the values are normally in a different order those in the formulaMap. Ideally what I need is to say is **if the string in formulaMap is the same as the string in valueMap, set the value in formulaMap to the same value as in valueMap.**

Let me know if you have any ideas as to what I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple:

```
formulaMap.putAll(valueMap);
```

If your value map contains key which are not contained in `formulaMap`, and you don't want to alter the original, do:

```
final Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>(valueMap);
map.keySet().retainAll(formulaMap.keySet());
formulaMap.putAll(map);
```

**Edit due to comment** It appears the problem was not at all what I thought, so here goes:

```
// The result map
for (final String key: formulaMap.keySet()) {
    map.put(formulaMap.get(key), valueMap.get(key));

// Either return the new map, or do:
valueMap.clear();
valueMap.putAll(map);
```

Comment: Thanks. My code is a lot more complicated than my example. Getting a current modification exception at the moment. Will try and get this to work.

Comment: With the example code it should not be a problem. Collections are very powerful ;)

Comment: Thanks, I have made a demo of the code in my question and it is working =D. There is clearly a problem with something else in my code.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but I don't want to open up another question on the same thing. Your answer is working perfectly for a part of my code, but the way I worded my question make it correct. Given: `valueMap { y=9.0, c=2.0, m=3.0, x=2.0}` and `formulaMap { y=dog, m=cat, x=bird, c=mouse}` I want to get output of `valueMap { dog=9.0, mouse=2.0, cat=3.0, bird=2.0}` This is essentially replacing the first value in valueMap with the second value from formulaMap. Please open a new answer or add to your answer if you have any ideas. Regards

Comment: OK, edited comments, but it looks like you have another problem, this looks rather strange as a data structure.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is input in multiple stages, so I have more than 2 linkedhashMaps that require manipulation and they are set out differently. Tricky logic to try and follow. Thanks for all the help =D

Comment: Is the **value in line 3** in your edit referring to valueMap?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Double> valueFormula: valueMap.entrySet()){          
  formulaMap.put(valueFormula.getKey(), valueFormula.value());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My code is a lot more complicated than my example. Getting a current modification exception at the moment. Will try and get this to work.

Comment: Unfortunately it is my code that has an error. But your solution definitely works. Thanks